# Echoing the elements of a shuffled array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I have an array of elements in PHP called...

```
$completeArray
```

...and I'm trying to store a randomized version of this array in my session called...

```
$_SESSION['videoArray']
```

...so I'm trying something like this...

```
$_SESSION['videoArray'] = shuffle($completeArray);
```

...but when I try to echo the first element of this randomized array like this...

```
$videoid = $_SESSION['videoArray'];
echo $videoid[0];
```

...all it's returning is the 'key' of the element. How do I randomize the array and be able to echo the actual elements of the new array?

Comment: Post the structure of your array. Is it multidimensional?

Comment: Associative. E.g. Array ( [0] => mF4HoG6LG44 [1] => zk-XPQNYxGg [2] => HIxIPz4MIAE [3] => oDG4shY9WBo [4] => wEUR7MaCtYI )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) take a reference of an array and Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

You should do:

```
shuffle($completeArray);
$_SESSION['videoArray'] = $completeArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethin like this:

```
 $_SESSION['videoArray'] = $completeArray;

shuffle($_SESSION['videoArray']);
```